The gpu usage rate is low, but it's stuttering too much
I'm using a blender and it's smooth to move the screen, but if I move an object with a high number of vertexes for animation, it stumbles too much. And I think it's too low usage. gpu usage is around 1% to 7%. Even though I'm moving the rigging. I wanted to increase usage and reduce stumblimg, so I tried it while searching the internet, such as Nvidia 3D setup and GeForce Experience, but it still stumbles. I bought a computer for the first time, do I need to set it up separately? I don't know what parts should be written down, so I'll write down only what seems important. AMD Ryzen 9 7900 12-Core Processor NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER At the bottom, the blender is running.And I used cuda and checked gpu.

Check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295284/blender-uses-cpu-instead-of-gpu?rq=1

Thank you for your reply, but I'm not a CPU overheating issue, and I'm using CUDA and I checked the gpu option.

In Blender, you need to go in Edit > Preferences > System, and select a GPU option there. Usually, the Optix option is the best for NVidia. If that isn't available, select a GPU option that is available.
Then in the render options, you must select GPU Compute for the renderer and some other things.
Make sure you have the latest GPU driver installed.

Thank you for your reply, but I'm not a CPU overheating issue, and I'm using CUDA and I checked the gpu option.

And I installed the latest NVIDIA driver. I also installed experience.

You are talking about render settings, while in the question there are remarks like "move an object with a high number of vertexes" and "moving the rigging", which sounds like working in the viewport to me, not rendering.
