# Unable to render using amd gpu, it is only using cpu

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am new to blender, I have a AMD Radeon 6650XT graphics card, But when I am rendering it is only using CPU, I have changed the GPU to HIP in preferences, but it I[image: These are the settings] still using CPU. Any solution[image: This shows the CPU usage while I am rendering.]s?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179170/gpu-not-rendering-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179170/gpu-not-rendering-in-cycles